# Upsert on Postgres: update all fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, upsert

I am trying to implement an upsert in postgres (an insert on constraint update). This is what my sql looks like:

```
INSERT into "foo" ("bar", "moo", "baz") VALUES (1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5) 
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT "composite_primary_key" DO NOTHING
```

I want to modify the `DO NOTHING` to something that will allow me to update ALL the fields for that row. I am not sure what the syntax should be since the docs do not explain it and there are not examples that do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Both! I have not found any examples that update all fields, nor the documentation shows syntax on how to do that.

Comment: That's because there is no special syntax, like `ON CONFLICT ... UPDATE SET ALL FIELDS`, you must mention all fields by name after `SET`, like the documentation suggests.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing 2.5 years later; in a database with many fields, it would be convenient to have a special syntax to update all fields in upsert with conflict.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update all columns with INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687267/how-to-update-all-columns-with-insert-on-conflict)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic `EXCLUDED` table to access the columns of your `VALUES` clause. That way, you don't have to repeat the values themselves in the `DO UPDATE SET` clause:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  i int,
  j int, 
  k int, 
  l int,
  m int,

  CONSTRAINT composite_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (i, j)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 2, 4, 6, 8) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT composite_primary_key DO UPDATE
SET
  k = excluded.k,
  l = excluded.l,
  m = excluded.m
RETURNING *;
```

The result is:

```
|i  |j  |k  |l  |m  |
|---|---|---|---|---|
|1  |1  |2  |3  |4  |
|2  |2  |4  |6  |8  |
```

It's not as poweful as you expected, but better than nothing, especially if you have a SQL builder available that can generate the query for you, dynamically, based on known schema meta data.

[More info in the PG documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Will this syntax work for a composite primary key as mentioned in OP?

Comment: @vhs: Yes of course. Just list all the columns, or list the constraint explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for performing an *upsert* using a named constraint looks like this:

```sql
on conflict on constraint "foo_pkey" do update
set moo = excluded.moo, boo = excluded.boo;
```

Applied to your original example with some modifications for clarity:

```sql
insert into foo (bar, baz, bat, moo, boo)
values ('a', 'b', 'c', 10, 20), ('d', 'e', 'f', 30, 40)
-- on conflict do nothing;
on conflict on constraint "foo_pkey" do update
set moo = excluded.moo, boo = excluded.boo;
```

[Fully working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=18acab5a852b49e2832f35d67b1e1c05). And a [reference guide](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/inserting-and-modifying-data/insert-on-conflict) from Prisma.