# How to update all columns with INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, upsert

I have a table with a single primary key. When I attempt to do an insert there may be a conflict caused by trying to insert a row with an existing key. I want to allow the insert to update all columns? Is there any easy syntax for this? I am trying to let it "upsert" all columns.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.5.

Comment: No, there is no shorthand for updating all columns. You have to include every column by name in the `set` part of the `update´

Comment: Please define "all columns". All columns of the target table? Or a (leading) subset? You have to very precise here, there are so many variations of desired behavior. You best show your exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script) and the UPSERT statement you have. And if "all columns" is a subset of all table columns, define what should happen to excess columns in the table. Reset to NULL? Preserve values?

Comment: All columns of the target table. You answer below if very thorough, thanks!

Comment: Still applies for v13

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [`UPDATE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) *requires* to explicitly name target columns.
Possible reasons to avoid that:

- You have many columns and just want to shorten the syntax.
- You do not *know* column names except for the unique column(s).

*`"All columns"`* has to mean *"all columns of the target table"* (or at least *"leading columns of the table"*) in matching order and matching data type. Else you'd have to provide a list of target column names anyway.

Test table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id    int PRIMARY KEY
, text  text
, extra text
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 'foo')
, (2, 'bar')
;
```

### 1. `DELETE` & `INSERT` in single query instead

***Without knowing any column names except `id`.***

Only works for *"all columns of the target table"*. While the syntax even works for a leading subset, excess columns in the target table would be reset to their respective column default (default NULL) with `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`) is needed to avoid concurrency / locking issues under concurrent write load, and only because there is no general way to lock not-yet-existing rows in Postgres ([*value locking*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Value_locking)).

Your special requirement only affects the `UPDATE` part. Possible complications do not apply where *existing* rows are affected. Those are locked properly. Simplifying some more, you can reduce your case to `DELETE` and `INSERT`:

```sql
WITH data(id) AS (              -- Only 1st column gets explicit name
   VALUES
      (1, 'foo_upd', 'a')       -- changed
    , (2, 'bar', 'b')           -- unchanged
    , (3, 'baz', 'c')           -- new
   )
, del AS (
   DELETE FROM tbl AS t
   USING  data d
   WHERE  t.id = d.id
   -- AND    t <> d              -- optional, to avoid empty updates
   )                             -- only works for complete rows
INSERT INTO tbl AS t
TABLE  data                      -- short for: SELECT * FROM data
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
RETURNING t.id;
```

In the Postgres MVCC model, an `UPDATE` is largely the same as `DELETE` and `INSERT` - except for some corner cases with concurrency, triggers, HOT updates, and big column values stored out of line, "TOASTed" values. Since you want to replace all rows anyway, just remove conflicting rows before the `INSERT`. Deleted rows remain locked until the transaction is committed. The `INSERT` might only find conflicting rows for previously non-existing key values if a concurrent transaction happens to insert them concurrently (after the `DELETE`, but before the `INSERT`).

You would lose additional column values for affected rows in this special case. No exception raised. But if competing queries have equal priority, that's hardly a problem: the other query won for *some* rows. Also, if the other query is a similar UPSERT, its alternative is to wait for this transaction to commit and then updates right away. "Winning" could be a Pyrrhic victory.

About "empty updates":

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

#### No, my query must win!

OK, you asked for it:

```sql
WITH data(id) AS (                   -- Only 1st column gets explicit name
   VALUES                            -- rest gets default names "column2", etc.
     (1, 'foo_upd', NULL)            -- changed
   , (2, 'bar', NULL)                -- unchanged
   , (3, 'baz', NULL)                -- new
   , (4, 'baz', NULL)                -- new
   )
, ups AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl AS t
   TABLE  data                       -- short for: SELECT * FROM data
   ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
   SET    id = t.id
   WHERE  false                      -- never executed, but locks the row!
   RETURNING t.id
   )
, del AS (
   DELETE FROM tbl AS t
   USING  data     d
   LEFT   JOIN ups u USING (id)
   WHERE  u.id IS NULL               -- not inserted!
   AND    t.id = d.id
   -- AND    t <> d                  -- avoid empty updates - only for full rows
   RETURNING t.id
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl AS t
   SELECT *
   FROM   data
   JOIN   del USING (id)             -- conflict impossible!
   RETURNING id
   )
SELECT ARRAY(TABLE ups) AS inserted  -- with UPSERT
     , ARRAY(TABLE ins) AS updated;  -- with DELETE & INSERT
```

How?

- The 1st CTE `data` just provides data. Could be a table instead.
- The 2nd CTE `ups`: UPSERT. Rows with conflicting `id` are not changed, but also **locked**.
- The 3rd CTE `del` deletes conflicting rows. They remain locked.
- The 4th CTE `ins` inserts *whole rows*. Only allowed for the same transaction
- The final `SELECT` is optional, to show what happened.

To check for empty updates test (before and after) with:

```
SELECT ctid, * FROM tbl; -- did the ctid change?
```

The (commented out) check for any changes in the row `AND t <> d` works even with NULL values because we are comparing two typed row values [according to the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#COMPOSITE-TYPE-COMPARISON)

> two NULL field values are considered equal, and a NULL is considered larger than a non-NULL

But all columns must support `=` / `<>` operators for the row comparison to work. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

### 2. Dynamic SQL

This works for a subset of leading columns too, preserving existing values.

The trick is to let Postgres build the query string with column names from the system catalogs dynamically, and then execute it.

See related answers for code:

- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)
- [Bulk update of all columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63883/3684)
- [SQL update fields of one table from fields of another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one/23283792#23283792)

Comment: A very important difference between UPDATE and DELETE+INSERT is that it will cause different triggers to fire, which is a problem if triggers are important to you.

Comment: You had me at "The UPDATE syntax requires to explicitly name target columns."! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Erwin Brandstetter's answer seems to fail when the `id` column is not the first column.

The following uses a snippet from [one of his other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283792/5282719) to reproduce the 'return ins/ups' functionality in my case:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
SELECT
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS res_tbl; CREATE TABLE res_tbl AS
 WITH ins AS (
       INSERT INTO dest
       TABLE  src                      -- short for: SELECT * FROM data
       ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
       SET    id = dest.id
       WHERE  false                    -- never executed, but locks the row!
       RETURNING id
    ),
    repl AS (
        UPDATE dest
        SET   (' || string_agg(          quote_ident(column_name), ',') || ')
            = (' || string_agg('src.' || quote_ident(column_name), ',') || ')
        FROM   src
        WHERE  src.id = dest.id
        AND    src <> dest             -- avoids empty updates ¹
        RETURNING dest.id
    )
 SELECT ARRAY(TABLE ins)  AS inserted  -- with UPSERT
      , ARRAY(TABLE repl) AS updated   -- with DYNAMIC UPDATE
;'
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name   = 'src'     -- table name, case sensitive
AND    table_schema = 'public'  -- schema name, case sensitive
AND    column_name <> 'id'      -- all columns except id)
);
END
$do$;
```

¹ Only works for full-row updates where all columns are comparable (e.g. `jsonb` not `json`).

Comment: Yes, important detail! All columns must support `=` / `<>` operators for the row comparison to work. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296054/939860